# How to fix slow parachain block time on rococo-local?

Tags: rococo, parachain-collator, block-production, rococo-local, local

Hello valuable Substrate community,

I started two rococo-local relaychain validators and one custom parachain. The target block time of the parachain is 12 seconds, but the actual block time is 24 seconds on average.

I am using a MacBook Air M1.

How can I reduce the block time to 12 seconds?

What is the cause of the slow block production on my local setup?

Comment: How many validators are you running? Try running one more!

Comment: I run two validators for the local Rococo relaychain and one collator on my local parachain. Thanks for the tip! I will try this.

Comment: Thanks, two collators fixed the problem!

Comment: Could you provide the answer to your question so this question is useful for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem of a block time of 24 seconds you need to add an additional parachain collator.

I just started two local rococo relay chain nodes and one parachain collator.

Then after Brunos suggestion I started another parachain collator and now the block time is consistently 12 seconds as expected.

To run two parachain collators you can follow the commands:

```bash
# Collator1
./target/release/polkadot-parachain --collator --alice --force-authoring --tmp --port 40335 --ws-port 9946 -- --execution wasm --chain ../polkadot/rococo-local-cfde.json --port 30335

# Collator2
./target/release/polkadot-parachain --collator --bob --force-authoring --tmp --port 40336 --ws-port 9947 -- --execution wasm --chain ../polkadot/rococo-local-cfde.json --port 30336
```

More on this [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus#manual-setup).